# Is there any method to block the installation of an android app, if the device is rooted?

Tags: android, installation, block, device, root

I would like to know if there is any way to block the installation of an android app, at installation time. I know there are ways to obstruct the execution like the methods listed below, but I would like to know if it is possible to apply some control in the installation phase of the app.

```
private static boolean checkRootMethod1() {
String buildTags = android.os.Build.TAGS;     
return buildTags != null && buildTags.contains("test-keys"); }  


private static boolean checkRootMethod2() {     
String[] paths = { "/system/app/Superuser.apk", 
"/sbin/su", "/system/bin/su", "/system/xbin/su",  
"/data/local/xbin/su", "/data/local/bin/su", 
"/system/sd/xbin/su",              
"/system/bin/failsafe/su", "/data/local/su", "/su/bin/su"};     
for (String path : paths) {         
if (new File(path).exists()) return true;}     
return false; } 

private static boolean checkRootMethod3() {     
Process process = null;     try {          
process = new ProcessBuilder("/system/xbin/which", "su").start(); 
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));         
return in.readLine() != null;     }  
catch (Throwable t) {         return false;     } 
finally {         if (process != null) process.destroy();     } }
```

Comment: you can do **nothing** when app is being installed. You can't execute your code on installation. There is no way. But what you can do is to check whatever you want when the app is launched (and close it for example, if something is wrong, like if user has root)

Comment: What I am looking for is a way to stop/abort the installlation prosess if the devices is rooted, is there some control sentece or method to detect the user profile or the user permissions used to run the installation? for example: control sentece or method's used to know the android version and abort the installation for devices with lower versions than 4.4.

Comment: to `abort the installation for devices with lower versions than 4.4.` you can use min SDK value of 19 (which means Android 4.4).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute this method and check the status code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

If it returns a process object , then you will know the device is rooted and if it does not , you can let the user use the app.

Comment: Wouldn't this just prompt the user to give root access to the app if the phone is rooted? The user could just deny this particular app root and then it  won't know the phone is rooted